# Left join returns fewer rows than select * on the left table?

Tags: sql, database, impala

I'm trying to do a left join with the right table. But on the left outer join, the results shows fewer rows on the left join than the select statement on the LHS table - why?

```
[hadoop-29:21000] > SELECT 
                  >   COUNT (*) 
                  > FROM 
                  >   state_vectors_data4 
                  >   left OUTER JOIN position_data4 ON (state_vectors_data4.lastcontact = position_data4.maxtime 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.icao24 = position_data4.icao24)
                  > WHERE 
                  >   state_vectors_data4.time >= 1677628800 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.time < 1677628810
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.hour >= 1677628800 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.hour <= 1677632400 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lat > 22.707434526056968 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lat < 71.83985097021925 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lon < -49.97631795370285 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lon > -168.4528775341493 
                  >   AND position_data4.hour >= 1677628800 
                  >   AND position_data4.hour <= 1677632400;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 13260    |
+----------+
```

How is it possible that an inner join returns fewer rows than the select statement on the LHS table? What am I missing here?

```
[hadoop-29:21000] > SELECT 
                  >    COUNT(*) 
                  > FROM 
                  >   state_vectors_data4
                  > 
                  > WHERE
                  >   state_vectors_data4.time >= 1677628800 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.time < 1677628810
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.hour >= 1677628800 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.hour <= 1677632400 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lat > 22.707434526056968 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lat < 71.83985097021925 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lon < -49.97631795370285 
                  >   AND state_vectors_data4.lon > -168.4528775341493; 
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 34210    |
+----------+
```

If I do a left join, won't the number of rows in the left table be maintained, if no match a null would be added from the right table?

Comment: Move the position_data4 conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: `left join` with any condition on right (joined) table that doesn't handle `null` turns this join into `inner`, because `null`s coming from the right table evaluate condition to unknown/null

Answer (score 0):

You have extra condition on right table

```
              >   AND position_data4.hour >= 1677628800 
              >   AND position_data4.hour <= 1677632400;
```

So probably here you are loosing some records

Comment: Those should be moved to the ON clause, to get proper LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: That is the column by which the table is partitioned... and that condition is also present in the LHS table

Comment: @AndrewsD, do you want a LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN?

Comment: Something like this:
SELECT 
  COUNT (*) 
FROM 
  position_data4 
  right JOIN state_vectors_data4 
  ON state_vectors_data4.lastcontact = position_data4.maxtime 
  AND state_vectors_data4.icao24 = position_data4.icao24
  AND state_vectors_data4.time >= 1677628800 
  AND state_vectors_data4.time < 1677628810.......

Comment: Thank you for that, is there a way to do the WHERE before the join ?

Comment: You can use with clause and put your filters there (https://data-flair.training/blogs/impala-with-clause/)

Comment: Thank you @jarlh why does it make it a true join only when it is in the ON clause ?

Comment: In your version you first do the join and then filter out rows not meeting the conditions - in other words you do the join of left + right and then you remove the outcome if field from right is not as expected. When you move it to ON you are going to have your left side always full potentially with nulls from right side when condition is not meet